# How to launch analytical data (gtag) after consent it

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Im trying to manage consent cookies and analytics and ads tracking code by following this source:

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent

My code looks like this:

**gtag config**

```
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<?php echo $localBusiness->getAnalyticsId(); ?>"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

    // Default ad_storage to 'denied'.
    gtag('consent', 'default', {
      'analytics_storage': 'denied',
      'ad_storage': 'denied'
    });

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('set', 'url_passthrough', true);
    /** Adds here gtag config command with conversion Id */
    gtag('config', '<?php echo $localBusiness->getAdsId(); ?>');
    gtag('config', '<?php echo $localBusiness->getAnalyticsId(); ?>');

  </script>
```

**update consent**

```
consentAdsAnalytics: function() {

  var hasAdsConsent = this.getCookie('lorraine-cookies-advertisement');

  if (hasAdsConsent == 'yes') { 
    gtag('consent', 'update', { 
      'ad_storage': 'granted'
    });
  } else {
    gtag('consent', 'update', { 
      'ad_storage': 'denied'
    });
  } 

  var hasAnalyticsConsent = this.getCookie('lorraine-cookies-analytics');

  if (hasAnalyticsConsent == 'yes') {
    gtag('consent', 'update', { 
      'analytics_storage': 'granted'
    });
  } else {
    gtag('consent', 'update', { 
      'analytics_storage': 'denied' 
    });
  } 

},
```

The problem is that when I click consent button, the visit isnt countend inmediantly, I need to navigate trough the web to begin to count visits from user granted and thus, I lose referal data.

Do you know how is to launch a signal or something similar when I accept the consent.

Comment: I think that I have fixed it calling to gtag('event', 'page_view'); after accept button is clicked.